# Formatting Date from arabic to english using momentjs

Tags: typescript, momentjs, locale

I am trying to format a date which is in arabic to english using moment js

```
var mom = moment("٣٠‏/١١‏/٢٠٢٠","l", 'ar', true);
        if(mom.isValid()) {
        schedule.startTime.dateText= mom.locale('en').format('MM/DD/YYYY'); 
}
```

This does not seem to work I get mom value as "Invalid Date". `"٣٠‏/١١‏/٢٠٢٠"` is the value from backend how do I convert to english?

Answer (score 0):

Just try specifying the format inside moment, and it should work fine.

Code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bas-fg1c2?file=/src/index.js:61-169

```js
const arabicDate = "٣٠‏/١١‏/٢٠٢٠";
console.log(moment(arabicDate, "YYYY/MM/DD").locale("en").format("YYYY/MM/DD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/locale/ar-sa.js"></script>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me in node js 16.14.2, moment 2.29.1

Answer (score 0):

pass in the local of the input string to the 3rd argument

```js
moment(
  moment().locale('ar').format('YYYY/MM/DD'),
  'YYYY/MM/DD',
  'ar'
)
```

works for me in moment 2.29.1 and nodejs 16.14.2